# Oracle Express Edition (Browser Interface) vs. SQL Plus Commd Line

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am using Application Express (OracleXE 11g Express Edition installed on Win7 32-bit) on-line and the below stored procedure compiles and executes successfully with no errors. When compiling in SQL Plus command line, code compiles successfully, but when I execute, it gives me an error. Now I already solved the error (code snippet shown below), **my question is why doesn't the database engine in Application Express throw an error ? Hope I am explaining my question correctly.**

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE DATE_DIMENSION
(  
DATE_KEY DATE NOT NULL,
FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
DAY_OF_WEEK NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL,
DAY_OF_MONTH NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
DAY_OF_YEAR NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH_INDICATOR CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
WEEK_ENDING_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
MONTH_NUMBER NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
MONTH_NAME VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
YEAR_MONTH CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
QUARTER_NUMBER NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL,
YEAR_QUARTER CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
YEAR_NUMBER NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT DATE_DIMENSION_PK PRIMARY KEY (DATE_KEY)
)
/
```

Stored Procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE sp_DATE_DIMENSION(v_START_YEAR IN INT, v_END_YEAR IN INT) AS

--Declare two variables as DATE datatypes
v_CURRENT_DATE DATE;
v_END_DATE     DATE;

BEGIN

--Assign the start year and end year to it's respective variables
v_CURRENT_DATE := TO_DATE('0101' || v_START_YEAR, 'MMDDYYYY');
v_END_DATE     := TO_DATE('1231' || v_END_YEAR,   'MMDDYYYY');

--Clear/Dump what is currently stored in the table
DELETE FROM DATE_DIMENSION;

--Check the condition to see if the start year is less than the end year (Input Parameters)
WHILE v_CURRENT_DATE <= v_END_DATE
LOOP
--DATE_DIMENSION Table
INSERT INTO DATE_DIMENSION
(
DATE_KEY,
FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION,
DAY_OF_WEEK,
DAY_OF_MONTH,
DAY_OF_YEAR,
LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR,
LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH_INDICATOR,
WEEK_ENDING_DATE,
MONTH_NUMBER,
MONTH_NAME,
YEAR_MONTH,
QUARTER_NUMBER,
YEAR_QUARTER,
YEAR_NUMBER       
)    
VALUES
(
v_CURRENT_DATE,                                 --DATE_KEY
TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'Day, Month DD, YYYY'), --FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'D')) -1,     --DAY_OF_WEEK
TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'DD'),                   --DAY_OF_MONTH        
TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'DDD'),                  --DAY_OF_YEAR
CASE                                               --LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR
    WHEN TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'FMDay') = 'Saturday' THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END,
CASE                                            --LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH_INDICATOR
    WHEN LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) = TO_DATE(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END,
CASE                                            --WEEK_ENDING_DATE OF   CURRENT WEEK ENDING ON SATURDAY
    WHEN TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'FMDay') = 'Saturday' THEN v_CURRENT_DATE
    ELSE NEXT_DAY(v_CURRENT_DATE,'SATURDAY')
END,
TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'MM'),                   --MONTH_NUMBER
TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'MONTH'),                --MONTH_NAME
TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'MONTH YYYY'),           --YEAR_MONTH        
TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'Q'),                    --QUARTER_NUMBER
TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY Q'),               --YEAR_QUARTER
TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY')                  --YEAR_NUMBER    

);
--Increment and assign the current date value to be re-evaluated
v_CURRENT_DATE := v_CURRENT_DATE + 1;

END LOOP;
END;
```

FYI - This piece of code solved my issue to make it execute using SQL Plus.

```
CASE                                            --LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH_INDICATOR
    WHEN LAST_DAY(v_CURRENT_DATE) = v_CURRENT_DATE THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END,
```

Comment: And what is the error, resp. your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are saying that neither environment threw a compilation error but one environment threw a runtime error.  I would guess in that case that you've written code that depends on environmental settings that are different in the two environments.

Looking at your `LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR`, that is in fact what you did by passing a `DATE` to `TO_DATE`.  Functionally, that doesn't make sense, `to_date` does not take a `DATE` as a parameter, it only accepts a `VARCHAR2`.  When you call

```
TO_DATE(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

therefore, Oracle has to do a few things.

First, it implicitly casts `v_current_date` to a string.  Because it is an implicit cast, it will use your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting.  Every session in a database may have a different `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` for a single session can change over time so the behavior of this implicit cast is not known at compile time.  If your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD-MON-RR`, which is the default setting if you did an Oracle client install on an English language Windows machine, the string that is passed to `to_date` would be "20-FEB-15" (assuming you called the procedure today).  If your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD/MM/YYYY`, the string passed to `to_date` would be "20/02/2015".

Next, it calls `to_date` passing in the string that was just generated and the format mask that you specified.  If you happen to be in a session where the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` matches the format mask you passed to `to_date`, you'll get the same `date` back from `to_date`.  If there is a mismatch, however, you may get an error (a string in the format DD-MON-YYYY will never convert to a valid date in the MM/DD/YYYY format) or you may get an unexpected result (a string in the format DD/MM/YYYY may convert to a valid date using the MM/DD/YYYY format mask but that date won't be the same one that you started with-- March 1 would be converted to January 3 for example).

If you want your code to run correctly regardless of the environment, avoid implicit casts.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing this:

```
WHEN LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
  = TO_DATE(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') THEN 'Y'
```

But `v_current_date` is already a DATE type, so for both of those calls to `to_date`, you're really doing `to_date(to_char(v_current_date), 'MM/DD/YYYY')`, and the `to_char` is using your session NLS_DATE_FORMAT - which is presumably MM/DD/YYYY in Apex, but something else in SQL*Plus.

You haven't shown your actual error, so I'm speculating a little, but you're effectively doing something like:

```
to_date(to_char(v_current_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

That would work sometimes, but get an invalid month error if the day of the month is after the 12th, since it's transposing the month and day numbers. Or your NLS setting mat be using MON, which would get the same error as Oracle is quite forgiving about using names instead of month numbers. Or some other format which gives a different error - there are several you could hit.

Your fix, to just use `WHEN LAST_DAY(v_CURRENT_DATE) = v_CURRENT_DATE`, avoids both the explicit conversion to a date, and the implicit conversion from a date to string, so there is no impact from your NLS settings.

Comment: I took a look at the NLS_DATE_FORMAT values in Apex and SQL Plus and found you are correct with Apex and SQL Plus is showing this format DD-MON-RR.